# Building a variable that combines several enumerations in an enormous list

Tags: python, list, combinatorics

I'd like to come up with the simplest way possible to create an enormous list.

Let's say I have three six-sided dice, so they'll each have a value of `randint(1,6)`.
I want the set of values that encompasses every possible way to combine those 3 numbers, so it could be die1 * die2 + die3 or it could be die1 ** die3 - die2, etc.

I'd like to define some variable Z which equals addition, subtraction, multiplcation, etc.  That way, I could say die1 Z die2 Z die3 and it would get me an enormous list, without me having to type it out.  Is this possible in Python? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Expressly yourself more clearly. What do you want to achieve? How can a variable equal several operations? What does that actually mean?

Comment: I think I need something like a list comprehension, I just don't know how to do it with operations instead of numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing to know here is that you can pass a function as an argument to another function (or in a list). Once you understand that this problem becomes much easier to solve.

If you want a list comprehension:

```
from operator import add,sub,mul,div
funcs = [add,sub,mul,div]
die = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

results = [f(x,y) if y != 0 else None for x in die for y in [g(z,w) for z in die for w in die for g in funcs] for f in funcs]
```

Note that contains "None" where a division by zero would have normally occurred.

It's way clearer if you split it out into a function though. It takes two lists of number and a list of operations and returns all results:

```
def results(funcs, xs, ys):
  out = []
  for f in funcs:
    for x in xs:
      for y in ys:
        try:
          out.append(f(x,y))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
          pass
  return out
```

This has nothing where a division by zero would have occurred. Use like `results(funcs,die,results(funcs,die,die))` to get all results.

Both of these have a lot of duplicates in their outcomes, so depending on what you actually want to do you might want a `set` instead of a `list`.

Also, just thought of it, but depending on what you're planning to do you could get `results` to return a generator instead:

```
def results(funcs, xs, ys):
  for f in funcs:
    for x in xs:
      for y in ys:
        try:
          yield f(x,y)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
          pass
```

If you're working on really large result sets but only want to look at them one by one this is a better option than building the whole list.

Comment: The [`operator`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html) standard module would be useful here, instead of redefining your own operations.

Comment: Good one. I didn't know that existed. I'll fix it up, then!

Comment: Thats very helpful, thanks. The duplicates are no problem - I'm working on a game, and just to give you a better idea of what I'm getting at I'll explain it. You have a target number, lets say its 100, that you're trying to get to with the 3 dice. If your 3 dice values to work with are 1, 1, 1, you could never get the target of 100. So I want to generate a list of every possible number you COULD get, and then compare the answer the player gives to that list.  So if whoever was playing the game typed in 100 even though they couldn't possibly get it, the game would tell them that was impossible.

Comment: And this accounts for 3 different dice, right? Seems that way from all the stuff under 'results'.  Also, does it account for different orders of the numbers? So not just, for example, (x * y) - z, but also (z * x) - y.  Again, thanks.

Comment: It doesn't account for change in order, but it's pretty easy to add in (I'll leave that up to you). The `results(funcs, die, results(funcs, die, die))` call uses three (as you can see three `die` in there), but you could easily add more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to ask how to best overload an operator for the Cartesian product in python.

Try using `product` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import *
die_outcomes = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list(product(product(die_outcomes, die_outcomes), die_outcomes))
```